# Gap between header and rest of calendar

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar

I am having problem with rendering fullcalendar in my asp.net mvc application. Library I am using is Fullcalendar jquery. 
As shown by the lower arrow in picture,blue event date range between times is actually between 12 am and 1 am, but in calendar event marked in blue exceeds 1 am. Why? It also seems that there is some kind of a gap as shown by the above arrow between header and the rest of calendar. [See the picture_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOgqK.png).[See the picture_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwqbg.png)

Here is cshtml code:

```
    model OrdinacijaS.Termin

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>Termin</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Pocetak)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Pocetak, new { id = "textBoxPocetak" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Pocetak)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Kraj)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Kraj, new { id = "textBoxKraj" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Kraj)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Pacijent_PacijentId, "Pacijent")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("Pacijent_PacijentId", String.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Pacijent_PacijentId)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Zahvat_ZahvatId, "Zahvat")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("Zahvat_ZahvatId", String.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Zahvat_ZahvatId)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" id="submitButton" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}



<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

<div id="calendar"></div>

@*<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />@
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.print.css" rel="stylesheet" media="print" />*@

<link href='/Content/fullcalendar.css' rel='stylesheet' /> 
<link href='/Content/fullcalendar.print.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />
```

Here is javascript code:

```
@section Scripts {
    @*@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")*@

@*<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js" rel="stylesheet"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.min.js" rel="stylesheet"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/locale/hr.js" rel="stylesheet"></script>*@
<script src='Scripts/jquery.min.js' rel="stylesheet"></script>
<script src='Scripts/moment.min.js' rel="stylesheet"></script>
<script src='Scripts/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js' rel="stylesheet"></script>
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function(myevents){
            var myevents = [];
            $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                type: "GET",
                asyc:false,
                url: "/Termin/getTermin",
                success: function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (i, v) {                       

                        myevents.push({
                            title: v.Ime,
                            description: "some description",
                            start: moment(v.Pocetak),
                            end: v.Kraj != null ? moment(v.Kraj) : null,
                            color: "#378006",
                            allDay: false
                        });

                    })
                    alert(myevents.length);
                    GenerateCalendar(myevents);

                },
                error: function (error) {
                    alert(error);
                }
            })
        })

        GenerateCalendar();
            function GenerateCalendar(myevents) {
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('destroy');
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar({


                    defaultDate: new Date(),
                    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',                  
                    timeFormat: 'h(:mm)a',
                    header: {

                        left: 'prev, next, today',
                        center: 'title',    
                        right: 'month, basicWeek, basicDay, agenda'
                    },

                    eventLimit: true,
                    eventColor: "#378006",                 
                    events: myevents,
                    selectable: true,
                    allDaySlot: false,

                    select: function(start, end, allDay) {
                        endtime = moment(end).format('YYYY/MM/DD hh:mm');
                        starttime = moment(start).format('YYYY/MM/DD hh:mm');
                        var mywhen = starttime + ' - ' + endtime;

                        $("#textBoxPocetak").val(starttime);
                        $("#textBoxKraj").val(endtime);

                    },
                    businessHours: {

                        dow: [1, 2, 3, 4], 

                        start: '8:00am',
                        end: '4:00pm', 
                    }

                })

            }
            $("#submitButton").on('click', function () { 

                //var myEvent = [];

                //myEvent.push({
                //    title: 'Long Event',
                //    start: '2017-08-08T08:30:00',
                //    end: '2017-08-08T09:30:00'
                //}); 


                //myEvent = {
                //    title: 'Long Event',
                //    start: '2017/08/08 08:30',
                //    end: '2017/08/08 09:30'
                //};
                //$('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', myEvent, 'stick');

                //myEvent = {
                //    title: 'Long Event',
                //    start: $('#textBoxPocetak').val(), 
                //    end: $('#textBoxKraj').val()
                //};


                //$('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent',myEvent,true);

                //$('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', {
                //    title: 'Long Event',
                //    start: '2017-08-08T08:30:00',
                //    end: '2017-08-08T09:30:00'
                //}, true);

                //$("#calendar").fullCalendar('addEventSource', myEvent);
                //$('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', myEvent);



            });
    </script>


}
```

Here is css code:

```
<style>
    .fc-sun{ 
    color:#FFF; 
    background: red;
}
 .fc-clear { 
    clear: none !important; 
}
</style>
```

Comment: You will have to include at least the cshml part for rendering this calendar, the relevant css and also mention which library this is from.

Comment: " As shown by the lower arrow in picture,blue event date range between times is actually between 12 am and 1 am". Is it? On the picture you've shown, the arrow is clearly somewhat _below_ 1am, as is the blue area. Can you be more precise about your problem? What actual times get reported when the "select" callback runs?

Comment: "What actual times get reported when the "select" callback runs?" It reports date range between start date of 12 am and end date of 1 am.As if date range show on calendar is somehow shifted and it exceeds 1 am by a little - but very visible. Please take a look at Picture_2 in my edited question. I made a selection that is marked in blue. Pocetak filed is the date start and Kraj field is the date end of what the selection returned. You can see that exceeds 2:00 on calendar but in the Kraj text field is shown 2:00.

Comment: Judging by your screenshot you seem to have used some custom CSS which impacts on the calendar. Please remove that and use the fullCalendar default CSS and see if your problem still exists. Most likely it's some conflicting / incorrect CSS which is causing the issue. Obviously I can't see what exact CSS you've used just based on the screenshot and your existing code samples.

Comment: A couple of other general points about the code as well: You seem to include the fullCalendar library twice (fullcalnendar.min.js from the CDN and then fullcalendar.js from your own server). At best this is inefficient, at worst it could cause errors. Please ensure you only have one version of each required library (moment, jquery, fullCalendar) - and also the same for the CSS files.

Comment: Secondly, I'd advise you not to use `async:false` for your ajax call - it locks the browser when being used, causing bad user experience. If the call takes longer than expected, the user might think the browser has crashed, since they cannot click on anything. Also `async:false` is deprecated in some browsers already so you can expect it to stop working in future. There's almost never any need for it.

Comment: Thirdly the way you're loading your events into the calendar is unusual - you load _all_ the events regardless of date, as effectively a static array. Although fullCalendar can work like this, it's not efficient. Really you should define your events feed as dynamic, like this: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/, or if that's too restrictive, like this: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_function/ That way, it only fetches the events needed for the current view and date range, not years of previous ones that likely won't get viewed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for delayed answer, but (I think) I found a solution. I implemented FullCalendar jquery using **MVC 4** application in Visual Studio 2013. MVC4 doesn't come with included bootstrap.js dependency,like later versions of MVC (MVC5 for example). It seems that Full Calendar jquery is somehow connected or depended on bootstrap.js becasue the moment after I installed booststrap.js (via Nugget)and included it in my MVC4 procjet the problem solved.